# A switch case program in python

Tags: python, mysql

i am struggling to get a switch case program in python,when i run the script i want to display three options

Enter your choice :

1.Insert Records

2.Update Records

3.Display Records

and after seeing these,the user should be able to enter his choice.Since am new to python i googled and found that there is no switch case in python.

```
def main():
    print("Enter your choice : ")
    print("1.Insert Records \n2.Update Records \n3.Display Records")
    choice = sys.argv[1]
    if(choice == 1):
        print 1
    if(choice == 2):
        print 2
    if(choice == 3):
        print 3
    else:
        print("You entered a wrong choice")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This is what i tried but its of no use, because it needs to enter choice at the time of running the script(eg. `python abc.py 1`)

Comment: `sys.argv` values are always all strings..

Comment: It's unclear whether this is about `switch` or getting user input. Have you looked at the built-in `input()` function?

Comment: the user can enter his choice only after looking at the options, how do i achieve this??

Comment: This question is not mysql related, can you change that?

Comment: Hi tintin, could you solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of switch/case, you can use a dict, like this:

```
from sys import argv

def insertRecord(args):
  ...

def updateRecord(args):
  ...

def displayRecords(args):
  ...

{
  1 : insertRecords,
  2 : updateRecords,
  3 : displayRecords
}[argv[1]](argv[2])
```

If you want to catch a default case, you can add something like this:

```
from sys import argv

def insertRecord(args):
  ...

def updateRecord(args):
  ...

def displayRecords(args):
  ...

def printHelp():
  ...

try:
  {
    1 : insertRecords,
    2 : updateRecords,
    3 : displayRecords
  }[argv[1]](argv[2])    
except KeyError:
  printHelp()
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

`sys.argv` is a list of *strings*. You are trying to compare one of those to integers, and that won't work without conversion.

In this case, you don't need to convert, just compare to strings instead:

```
if choice == '1':
    print 1
elif choice == '2':
    print 2
elif choice == '3':
    print 3
else:
    print("You entered a wrong choice")
```

You can still convert the string to an integer first, allowing you to do more complex checks:

```
try:
    choice = int(sys.argv[1])
except ValueError:
    print("You entered a wrong choice")
else:
    if not 1 <= choice <= 3:
        print("You entered a wrong choice")
    else:
        print(choice)
```

If you are building an interactive menu, then perhaps the command line options are not the best choice here. Use the [`input()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) instead so you print prompts and use a series of exchanges. See [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response).

Answer (score 0):

Look at the description of [sys.argv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input). It is not used for input in runtime. Rather it is used to pass arguments to script when it is called. So this script:

```
import sys

print sys.argv
```

When called with `python script.py one two three` would print `['one', 'two', 'three']`

If you want to get user input on executiopn of the program you should use [input](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input). Look carefully at the details such as returned value etc.

The next issue as makred by Martijn is that python does not have switch-case. You should use `if-elif-else` constrcution.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to prompt the user for input. In python 2.x, use `raw_input` for that. Users enter strings, so I changed what you are looking for. And used `elif` to end the compares after you find a match.

```
def main():
    print("Enter your choice : ")
    choice = raw_input("1.Insert Records \n2.Update Records \n3.Display Records")
    if(choice == '1'):
        print 1
    elif(choice == '2'):
        print 2
    elif(choice == '3'):
        print 3
    else:
        print("You entered a wrong choice")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are able to pass the choice as argument OR it will ask.
I prefer the lambda-version in "switch-cases" to be sure it will only be executed when accessed.
This way you can replace print(1) etc. with a performance intense task and it won't run for every entry in the dict.

Python3 example:

```py
import sys
def get_input():
    print("Enter your choice : ")
    return input("1.Insert Records \n2.Update Records \n3.Display Records")

def main():
    choice = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv)>1 else get_input()
    {
        '1': lambda: print(1),
        '2': lambda: print(2),
        '3': lambda: print(3),
        '4': lambda: print(4),
        }.get(choice, lambda: print("You entered a wrong choice"))()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Same in python2:

```py
import sys
def get_input():
    print "Enter your choice : "
    return raw_input("1.Insert Records \n2.Update Records \n3.Display Records")

def print_val(val):
    print val

def main():
    choice = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv)>1 else get_input()
    {
        '1': lambda: print_val(1),
        '2': lambda: print_val(2),
        '3': lambda: print_val(3),
        '4': lambda: print_val(4),
        }.get(choice, lambda: print_val("You entered a wrong choice"))()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```